# Error running turtlesim turtlesim_node

Tags: ros2, turtlesim, turtlesim-node

I have a Windows 11 machine onto which IO have installed Ubuntu 22.04 using the Windows sub-system for Linux. I have followed the instructions to install ROS ( https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Installation/Ubuntu-Install-Debians.html )

I then followed the Next Steps linked and installed turtlesim but when attempting to run

```
ros2 run turtlesim turtlesim_node
```

I get the following error

```
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, xcb.
```

I followed advice from a post saying to use the `LDD` command to identify any missing dependencies but none were shown.

Any ideas how I can fix this, please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to get GUI dependencies and environment variables set up.

(1) Ensure you use **WSL2** as it has better support for GUI applications.

(2) Set up the **DISPLAY** environment variable with the IP address of your Windows machine for Linux applications running in WSL2 to show GUIs on this Windows host. This can be done as follows:

```
export DISPLAY=$(cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep nameserver | awk '{print $2}'):0
```

(3) Test that it works with a light GUI app (in the same terminal you ran the above command).

```
sudo apt update

sudo apt install xorg
sudo apt install x11-apps

xeyes
```

If the environment variable is correctly set, `xeyes` shows up as a small GUI that follows your mouse cursor. If it shows up, this means X11 Window system is correctly set up and you are ready to use ROS GUI apps too.

---

**Note:** You need to add the export command to Linux's `~/.bashrc` file not to do it every time you start a terminal, but verify first it solves the issue in the current terminal session.

Comment: I've check WSL using
wsl --list --verbose
and I see the following
  NAME            STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu-22.04    Running         2
I have also added the export command described in your reply and I have installed x11-apps
x@y~$ printenv|grep DISPLAY
DISPLAY=172.26.112.1:0
However when I run xeyes I still don't see a GUI
I did find another post suggesting another environment variable  QT_QPA_PLATFORM=offscreen
Using this one, I see to turtlesim coordinates and I don't see them with the DISPLAY env variable

Comment: Just tried again and realised it's still erroring with the new environment variable. The first line of the error message now reads
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display 172.27.96.1:0
and it takes a couple of minutes to abort

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, @Jevers. Please install `xorg` if not installed inside your Linux environment that uses WSL2 and try again. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance @robotawi . I've followed the updated advice (installed xorg) and still get the same error.

Comment: Was the issue fixed? If not, I can share the details from the very start, setting up WSL2.

Comment: I abandoned WSL and used Oracle Virtualbox and everything worked from the start